# Method, doesn't set property value

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
function Show() {
    this.showId = $("#meta-show-id").val();
    this.title = $("#meta-title").val();
    this.season = $("#meta-season").val();
    this.episode = $("#meta-episode").val();
    this.storageId = $("#meta-show-id").val() + '-' + $("#meta-season").val() + '-' + $("#meta-episode").val();
    this.torrents = [];
    this.putioId = null;
    this.status = null;
    this.subtitle = null;
}
Show.prototype = {
    constructor: Show,
    checkStorage: function() {
        var storage = new Storage();
        storage.get(this.storageId, function(data){
            if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)){
                console.log("empty");
            }
            else {
                this.subtitle = data.subtitle;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I call the `checkStorage()` method on `object`, method checks in `chrome.storage.sync` for data, and sets `object` `this.subtitle property`.

But this doesn't seem to work, `this.subtitle` value doesn't change.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you SURE you get values from "meta-show-id, meta-season etc?

Console.log? :)

Comment: yes, console.log prints data from, $("#meta-show-id").val() etc. It seams that object properties (this.subtitle, this.status ... are not accessuble in function(data){...} inside storage.get()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a normal result, and it happens because of scope changing. I don't know if `Storage` is has your own implementation (because it is used with `getItem` instead of `get`), but anyways, you are calling a method that I guess calls back the function you provide as a second argument, right?

And because this function is called from somewhere else, `this` is not the object that you want.

Here is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/6c2e6/1/

Check out logs, and see what `this` is. It's the Window, because my `test` function is at top level..